# Xamarin Android - Load a WebView using CookieContainer and javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview, xamarin

I am trying to load a WebView using the same sessionId as the other HttpWebRequests in my app, and the page has javascript that needs to run.

I am setting _webView.JaveScriptEnabled = true;

When I load the page using LoadUrl the javascript runs, but the ASP.NET_SessionId that is sent is not the same session id that my other HttpWebRequests send, and I haven't been able to set the CookieContainer:

> _webView.LoadUrl(apiBase + "/App/Index");

When I retrieve the page using a HttpWebRequest I am able to set the CookieContainer and load the page, but the javascript does not run:

> var httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(apiBase + "/App/Index"));
>      httpReq.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
>      var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
>      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
>      {
>          var viewResult = ;
>          _webView.LoadData (sr.ReadToEnd(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
>      }

How do I get both behaviors in one web call?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I needed to chang
_webView.LoadData (sr.ReadToEnd(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
to
_webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL (apiBase, sr.ReadToEnd(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");